# How to identify a domain controller by scanning a bunch of IP addresses?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, entra-id

I am looking for a way to determine what Ip addresses are acting as domain controllersin my network of arount 100,000 IP addresses. The main goal is to scan all of the machines and once I identify the machines that are acting as domain controller, we will figure out what users are connected to it. I can't runany WMI queries to any of the IP addresses. All I can do is scan my full network. So, is there any distinguish factor in a machine/Ip address that a domain controller have and a normal workstation or a member workstation don't have? Thanks

Comment: uhm ... resolving the domain name will list all domain controllers.

Comment: Log in to a DC and then check the AD configuration?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yes, you're right by using nltest /dclist:<domainname> . But the problem is, there are many domain names in my organization that I am not aware of.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: that may not always be accurate. It's common for domain controllers in spoke sites in large directories to not register.

Comment: I think if you want this to be taken seriously, more information and context would be VERY helpful. If this is a serious problem, this is a VERY large scope of work, and solutions should be as closely tailored to your situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All domain controllers listen on port 389, so you can use NMap to scan an address range with the ldap-rootdse script.

```
nmap -p 389 -T4 -A -v --script ldap-rootdse nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn/nn
```

The output for a domain controller is very distinctive.

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE VERSION
389/tcp open  ldap    Microsoft Windows Active Directory LDAP (Domain: contoso.com, Site: CONTOSO-LASite)
| ldap-rootdse: 
| LDAP Results
|   <ROOT>
|       currentTime: 20180911130405.0Z
|       subschemaSubentry: CN=Aggregate,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com
|       dsServiceName: CN=NTDS Settings,CN=CONTOSOLADC1,CN=Servers,CN=CONTOSO-LASite,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com
|       namingContexts: DC=contoso,DC=com
|       namingContexts: CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com
|       namingContexts: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com
|       namingContexts: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=contoso,DC=com
|       namingContexts: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=contoso,DC=com
|       defaultNamingContext: DC=contoso,DC=com
|       schemaNamingContext: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com
|       configurationNamingContext: CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com
|       rootDomainNamingContext: DC=contoso,DC=com
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.801
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.473
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.528
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.417
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.619
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.841
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.529
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.805
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.521
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.970
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1338
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.474
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1339
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1340
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1413
|       supportedControl: 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.9
|       supportedControl: 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.10
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1504
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1852
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.802
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1907
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1948
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1974
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1341
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2026
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2064
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2065
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2066
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2090
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2205
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2204
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2206
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2211
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2239
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2255
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2256
|       supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2309
|       supportedLDAPVersion: 3
|       supportedLDAPVersion: 2
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxPoolThreads
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxPercentDirSyncRequests
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxDatagramRecv
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxReceiveBuffer
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: InitRecvTimeout
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxConnections
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxConnIdleTime
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxPageSize
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxBatchReturnMessages
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxQueryDuration
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxDirSyncDuration
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxTempTableSize
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxResultSetSize
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MinResultSets
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxResultSetsPerConn
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxNotificationPerConn
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxValRange
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxValRangeTransitive
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: ThreadMemoryLimit
|       supportedLDAPPolicies: SystemMemoryLimitPercent
|       highestCommittedUSN: 3684288
|       supportedSASLMechanisms: GSSAPI
|       supportedSASLMechanisms: GSS-SPNEGO
|       supportedSASLMechanisms: EXTERNAL
|       supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
|       dnsHostName: CONTOSOLADC1.contoso.com
|       ldapServiceName: contoso.com:contosoladc1$@CONTOSO.COM
|       serverName: CN=CONTOSOLADC1,CN=Servers,CN=CONTOSO-LASite,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com
|       supportedCapabilities: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.800
|       supportedCapabilities: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1670
|       supportedCapabilities: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1791
|       supportedCapabilities: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1935
|       supportedCapabilities: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2080
|       supportedCapabilities: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2237
|       isSynchronized: TRUE
|       isGlobalCatalogReady: TRUE
|       domainFunctionality: 4
|       forestFunctionality: 4
|_      domainControllerFunctionality: 7
```

Comment: I'll try that. Can you tell me the distinctive factor I'll be looking at?

Comment: @DaniyalNaeem: I added it to the answer